# How to animated and drag white circle

Tags: css

I am trying to create this type of animation with jQuery svg.

First sorry about my English.

When user clicks on icon circle minor animated circle. And drag this to drag circle with dots minor.

See this link make this type animation:

http://christophergandrud.github.io/networkD3/

or any other type.

This is my website link http://horeko.seomonastery.com/

I don't know how to do this.

[image: this is my screen shot]

Please help me to create this type animation.

Comment: Can you please update the  code in fiddle, what you have tried till now.

Comment: You mean drag circles while lines are still connected?

Comment: yes line are connected